# Loading a parquet file from a GitHub repository

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, github, parquet

I tried to read a parquet (`.parq`) file I have stored in a GitHub project, using the following script:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import ipywidgets as widgets
import datetime
from ipywidgets import interactive
from IPython.display import display, Javascript

import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings('ignore')


parquet_file = r'https://github.com/smaanan/sev.en_commodities/blob/main/random_deals.parq'

df = pd.read_parquet(parquet_file, engine='auto')
```

and it gave me this error:

> ArrowInvalid: Could not open Parquet input source '': Parquet
> magic bytes not found in footer. Either the file is corrupted or this
> is not a parquet file.

Does anyone know what this error message means and how I can load the file in my GitHub repository? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the URL under the domain `raw.githubusercontent.com`.

As for your example:

```py
parquet_file = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/smaanan/sev.en_commodities/main/random_deals.parq'
df = pd.read_parquet(parquet_file, engine='auto')
```

Answer (score 2):

You can read parquet files directly from a web URL like this. However, when reading a data file from a git repository you need to make sure it is the raw file url:

```py
url = 'https://github.com/smaanan/sev.en_commodities/blob/main/random_deals.parq?raw=true'
```